# Updating the android picture gallery after saving an image with an Air app

Tags: android, mobile, air

I saved a picture locally through my Air app, but I need to call this MediaScanner to update the gallery,
so that the user could see the saved pic, like this solution :

[Updating gallery after taking pictures Gallery not showing all the pictures Android Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667623/updating-gallery-after-taking-pictures-gallery-not-showing-all-the-pictures-andr)

How do you do it through Air Mobile ?
Is it necessary to create a native extension ? 
if so, how ?

Thanks.

Comment: There are other ways to do that on android, I don't know on Air Mobile :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144840/how-can-i-refresh-the-gallery-after-i-inserted-an-image-in-android/9096984#9096984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a native extension and call it after the saving process is done.
A nice existing extension which refreshes the gallery can be found here :

[Fathah's Refresh Gallery ANE](http://blog.fathah.net/2012/03/air-native-extension-ane-to-refresh.html)

Comment: ANE link is dead, any idea where to download it from\?

Comment: i can t get to download the zip file, get some ads instead. But it's ok i just recreated it in  the meantime https://github.com/mikatalk/ANE-RefreshGallery-Android