# Taking pictures with camera on Android programmatically

Tags: android, image, camera

I have created an app with a button and wrote onClickListener for that button. I have tried several sample code examples and none of them worked. They all bring up the Android camera app and don't take photographs. I want some code which I can put in my onClickListener so when I press the button on the screen, a picture will be taken.

How can I make the camera take a picture when I press a button in an Android activity?

Comment: Refer the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977245/android-open-camera-from-button/40041381#40041381

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Look at following demo code.

Here is your XML file for UI,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Camera" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is your Java class file,

```
public class CameraDemoActivity extends Activity {
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store
        // pics taken by the camera using this application.
        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
        File newdir = new File(dir);
        newdir.mkdirs();

        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
                // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
                // and likewise.
                count++;
                String file = dir+count+".jpg";
                File newfile = new File(file);
                try {
                    newfile.createNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }

                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Specify the following permissions in your manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Your again puts the camera in preview mode but does not enable it take a snap by itself and then return. Can you please check? Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: you need to `click` on capture button to capture the image

Comment: Which button exactly? Do you mean the button specified in my layout or do you mean the button when the camera is in the preview mode? Please clarify.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: the button specified in your layout which has text written like `Camera` as mentioned in my answer

Comment: Fine. I uploaded the app on the device, clicked the "Camera" button.When I checked my gallery then there were no pics. Where are these picture files are really getting stored?Let say if I want to store these picture files on my HTC phone's gallery then can I do that? Please explain and clarify. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: the image has been stored in folder named `picFolder` but android doesn't know about newly created file.so you need to send broadcast to update it.have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667623/updating-gallery-after-taking-pictures-gallery-not-showing-all-the-pictures-andr`

Comment: This is honestly confusing. I need the complete code. Can you please direct me to a better link or tutorial? Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: you should start with `http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html`

Comment: If there's a method to capture images hiddenly?

Comment: even with the same answer you can programmatically press the camera button using this piece of code, **capture.performclick();**

Comment: @ranjithstar256: `camera.performclick();` can open camera only. it will not take picture directly. for that,user has to interact.

Comment: obviously, that code will press the capture(button variable here) button programmatically. you are right

Comment: Why did you have to create file before starting activity... Am not understanding. Someone explain to me please

Comment: In Nexus 7, the code opens the camera and I can press the icon to take the picture but .... It freezes after taking the picture (freeze on the taken picture). Then you have the options to return back or to retake the picture. Both option result in picture not taken (or not saved) !! how to solve this please ?

Comment: What is TAKE_PHOTO_CODE here cannot find the symbol error.

Comment: This "answer" and its entire comment thread is frustrating. This does NOT automatically take a picture programmatically at all.  All it does is programmatically LAUNCH the Camera via a button click, then the user has to INTERACTIVELY click again on the Camera view to accept the image.

Comment: It gives me error: Failed to handle method call
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/APP_NAME/1596889464576.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Comment: @Pawan if you are trying above Android 10, it will be problem because Google has restricted it. reference : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

Comment: FYI `startActivityForResult` is deprecated so consider using the new way, can be reference here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative

Answer (score 31):

There are two ways to take a photo:

1 - Using an Intent to make a photo

2 - Using the camera API

I think you should use the second way and there is a [sample code here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html) for two of them.

Comment: I am using this example.in second example application crashing.it says

 java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed

Comment: @AbdulWaheed i think you are using android 6.0+ which requires that you explicitly request permission at runtime before accessing the camera. What is your version of android?

Comment: The example uses the Camera class, which has been deprecated as of API 21 (Android 5.0, Lollipop). But even with requested permissions it crashes on button click.

Answer (score 6):

**You can use Magical Take Photo library.**

**1. try with compile in gradle**

```
compile 'com.frosquivel:magicaltakephoto:1.0'
```

**2. You need this permission in your manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

**3. instance the class like this**

// "this" is the current activity param

```
MagicalTakePhoto magicalTakePhoto =  new MagicalTakePhoto(this,ANY_INTEGER_0_TO_4000_FOR_QUALITY);
```

**4. if you need to take picture use the method**

```
magicalTakePhoto.takePhoto("my_photo_name");
```

**5. if you need to select picture in device, try with the method:**

```
magicalTakePhoto.selectedPicture("my_header_name");
```

**6. You need to override the method onActivityResult of the activity or fragment like this:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     magicalTakePhoto.resultPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     // example to get photo
     // imageView.setImageBitmap(magicalTakePhoto.getMyPhoto());
}
```

Note: Only with this Library you can take and select picture in the device, this use a min API 15.

Comment: This library is not updated. Please suggest updated library

Answer (score 3):

For those who came here looking for a way to take pictures/photos programmatically using both Android's Camera and Camera2 API, take a look at the open source sample provided by Google itself [here](https://github.com/google/cameraview).

Answer (score 2):

Take and store image in desired folder

```
 //Global Variables
   private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST = 101;
    private String imageName;
```

Take picture function

```
 public void captureImage() {

            // Creating folders for Image
            String imageFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/AutoFare";
            File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();

            // Generating file name
            imageName = new Date().toString() + ".png";

            // Creating image here
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(imageFolderPath, imageName)));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                    CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);

        }
```

Broadcast new image added otherwise **pic will not be visible in image gallery**

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 //Scan new image added
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/AutoFare/" + imageName).getPath()}, new String[]{"image/png"}, null);


 // Work in few phones
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/AutoFare/" + imageName)));

                    } else {
                        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/AutoFare/" + imageName)));
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Take Picture Failed or canceled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: yep, here is a full documentation with code https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Answer (score -1):

The following is a simple way to open the camera:

```
private void startCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath());
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Comment: what does that "way to open the camera" mean. Does it mean that you access somehow the picture and display it? Or does it rather mean that you use/open the "Camera App" on the smartphone?

Answer (score -5):

```
Intent takePhoto = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(takePhoto, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
```

and set
`CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST= 1 or 0`