# Detecting front facing camera and capturing image, android?

Tags: android, camera

I want to capture image from the front facing camera. 
Is there a way to detect front facing camera?
I searched a lot and the all the answers I found are quite old 2-3 yrs old.

Do I have to make a custom camera for it or is there any other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338037/android-using-front-facing-camera-to-take-a-picture

Comment: http://androideasylessons.blogspot.in/2012/09/open-front-camera-in-android-program.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the help of these links I was able to create my own front camera to take pictures

1. [Android using front facing camera to take a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338037/android-using-front-facing-camera-to-take-a-picture)
2. [Access front camera](http://androideasylessons.blogspot.in/2012/09/open-front-camera-in-android-program.html)
3. [Android developer camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Here is the link to final project

[Custom Front Camera](https://github.com/wishygupta/Front-Camera-Android)