# How to Take a Photo with the Camera App And also save as thumbnail and as Full-size Photo (resize & crop customly) in SD Card Two Folders?

Tags: android, android-camera, image-resizing, android-sdcard, android-camera-intent

I am new in android development. I want take an image from android camera tool then save as thumbnail and also save as Full-size (Resize & crop user defined).

I actually want thumbnail image show in `GridView` from one folder of SD Card then click one image then show full-size(1536 X 2048) image in one window from another folder of SD Card.

I search in google but not get absolute example or tutorial which is match two conditions.

For example

[developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)

[taking pictures with camera android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421694/taking-pictures-with-camera-android-programmatically)

[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

Please anybody help me, how to possible this. If my concept mismatch then modify to update my question. Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow bellow Steps:-

**1:-**

```
private  Bitmap getScaledBitMap(String filePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

if (filePath != null && filePath.contains("file")) {
    filePath = filePath.replace("file://", "");
}
Bitmap unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeBitmap(getResources(), filePath, reqWidth, reqHeight, ScalingLogic.CROP);
// Part 2: Scale image
Bitmap scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, reqWidth,reqHeight, ScalingLogic.CROP);
unscaledBitmap.recycle();

return scaledBitmap;
```

}

**2:-**

```
public class ScalingUtilities {

/**
 * Utility function for decoding an image resource. The decoded bitmap will
 * be optimized for further scaling to the requested destination dimensions
 * and scaling logic.
 *
 * @param res The resources object containing the image data
 * @param resId The resource id of the image data
 * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
 * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
 * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
 * @return Decoded bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Resources res, String pathName, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
            dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

    return unscaledBitmap;
}

/**
 * Utility function for creating a scaled version of an existing bitmap
 *
 * @param unscaledBitmap Bitmap to scale
 * @param dstWidth Wanted width of destination bitmap
 * @param dstHeight Wanted height of destination bitmap
 * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
 * @return New scaled bitmap object
 */
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
            dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
            dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;
}

/**
 * ScalingLogic defines how scaling should be carried out if source and
 * destination image has different aspect ratio.
 *
 * CROP: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure that at least
 * one of the two dimensions fit inside the requested destination area.
 * Parts of the source image will be cropped to realize this.
 *
 * FIT: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure both
 * dimensions fit inside the requested destination area. The resulting
 * destination dimensions might be adjusted to a smaller size than
 * requested.
 */
public static enum ScalingLogic {
    CROP, FIT
}

/**
 * Calculate optimal down-sampling factor given the dimensions of a source
 * image, the dimensions of a destination area and a scaling logic.
 *
 * @param srcWidth Width of source image
 * @param srcHeight Height of source image
 * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
 * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
 * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
 * @return Optimal down scaling sample size for decoding
 */
public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            return srcWidth / dstWidth;
        } else {
            return srcHeight / dstHeight;
        }
    } else {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            return srcHeight / dstHeight;
        } else {
            return srcWidth / dstWidth;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Calculates source rectangle for scaling bitmap
 *
 * @param srcWidth Width of source image
 * @param srcHeight Height of source image
 * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
 * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
 * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
 * @return Optimal source rectangle
 */
public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
            final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
            return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
        } else {
            final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
            final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
            return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
        }
    } else {
        return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
    }
}

/**
 * Calculates destination rectangle for scaling bitmap
 *
 * @param srcWidth Width of source image
 * @param srcHeight Height of source image
 * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
 * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
 * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
 * @return Optimal destination rectangle
 */
public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
        }
    } else {
        return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
    }
}
```

}

save this bitmap into required folder.

Comment: may be your answers correct but i don't khow how to come Bitmap Class, please explain step by step from android-camera intent , please

Answer (score 0):

Create a File

> private final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST=0;

```
 private String createNewFile()
{

 String dirctory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"test";
    File f = new File(dirctory);
    boolean isdirectory;
    if(!f.isDirectory())
    {
        isdirectory = f.mkdir();
    }else
    {
        isdirectory = true;
    }

    if(isdirectory)
    {
        dirctory  = dirctory +"/"+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+"captureImage.jpg";
        f = new File(dirctory);
        if(f.isFile())
            f.delete();
        try {
            f.createNewFile();

            return dirctory;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utility.Toast(mActivity, "Unable to create File");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else
    {
        Utiity.Toast(AgentSignUp.this, "Unable to create Directory");
    }
    return dirctory;
}
```

Step 2: fire intent:

> ```
>              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>             file_image = createNewFile();
>             if(file_image!=null)
>             {
>                 File file = new File(file_image);
>                 Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
>                 cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
>             }
>     startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
> ```

step 3: recieve in onActivity Result (check for sucess and failure)

> ```
>                 @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
>     {
>         if(requestCode==CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
>         {
>             File file = new File(file_image);
>             Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
>             doCrop(outputFileUri);// send to cropper or you can use this uri for upper code to get two size of images
>         }
> }
> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> }
> ```