# Reduce Image size while maintaining the quality

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, android-bitmap

I just want to know the different factors on which I can work on and reduce the size of any image by maintaining its quality.

Like Bitmap.compress is the one option for me.

Also which is the best encoding format (Jpeg, Png) which maintain quality with minimal size.

Comment: I may not answer your question but the tool tiny png https://tinypng.com/ reduce images by ~70% and the quality is the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494419/how-to-take-a-photo-with-the-camera-app-and-also-save-as-thumbnail-and-as-full-s/23494960#23494960

Comment: 'reduce size' means 'Same picture, stored using less bytes' or 'downsize picture to fit on my little screen'?

Comment: use JPG to maintain quality.

Comment: @NirHartmann It seems a good tool but I want to use it in my Android application. Thanks Man

Comment: It works great for me.[Try this...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573774/how-to-reduce-an-image-file-size-before-uploading-to-a-server?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

It depends of bitmap content. If you have a text or other solid color or contrast areas on your bitmap then PNG is your choice, because it preserves image quality.

If  it's a picture from camera then JPG is best.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

private Bitmap decodeFileFromPath(String path){
        Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            int inSampleSize = 1024;
            if (o.outHeight > inSampleSize || o.outWidth > inSampleSize) {
                scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(inSampleSize / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
            in.close();

            return b;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression) file format will not mess up with your bytes:

- PNG (default configuration = lossless)
- Tiff lossless (zip or lzw)
- JPEG lossless (a special type of JPEG. I don't think Android supports this out of the box)