# Take picture from android programmatically

Tags: android, image, capture

I am creating a photo editing app and trying to capture a photo from android camera. I use following code onPictureTaken :

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        BitmapFactory.Options opt;

        opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPictureSize();
        int height11 = size.height;
        int width11 = size.width;
        float mb = (width11 * height11) / 1024000;
        if (mb > 4f)
            opt.inSampleSize = 4;
        else if (mb > 3f)
            opt.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = null;
        bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opt);
        bitmapPicture=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture,(int)CaptureImage.screen_width,(int)CaptureImage.screen_height,false);
        if(((CaptureImage)context).cameraType==1){

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    if(((CaptureImage)context).screenType==0)
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    bitmapPicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture, 0, 0,
                            bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), matrix,
                            true);
        }
        // write captured image in sd card
        new File(Constants.IMAGES_PATH).mkdirs();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";
        File pictureFile = new File(Constants.IMAGES_PATH, photoFile);
        imgUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if(((CaptureImage)context).screenType==0){
                        if(((CaptureImage)context).cameraType==0)
                            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,""+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90);
                        if(((CaptureImage)context).cameraType==1)
                            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,""+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90);
             }
            else{
                        //if(((CaptureImage)context).cameraType==0)
                    //      exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,""+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270);
    //                  if(((CaptureImage)context).cameraType==1)
                            //exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,""+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180);
            }


            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.v("Error", exception.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.CAPTURED_IMAGE,imgUri);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity) context).finish();
    }
```

Above code is working on all phones but on nexus 4 when I use this code image is not getting saved and a blank screen is shown.

Comment: Define "all phones" and share your logcat.

Comment: @user3673182 you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421694/taking-pictures-with-camera-android-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: Captured image working on my phone but client have nexus.And i do not have nexus to check log of capture.