# Like we have android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING...do we have any method to invoke the timer of camera in extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera2

Please help me to invoke the camera timer using extras

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra ("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_TIMER", 1);
```

Comment: I guess this is what You need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917768/android-how-to-take-a-picture-based-on-a-timer

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no documented extra for that, in the public SDK documentation for [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

And in fact, CAMERA_FACING is not a documented extra either, so it's likely that it won't work on many devices or for many 3rd-party camera apps.

Comment: means i cant use the inbuild camera timer ?