# Capture Image programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

how i can Using camera to capture picture programmatically without touch the capture button in android like selfie stick using bluetooth sign.

Comment: Since you are new I urge you to take the tour from here http://stackoverflow.com/tour so that you can ask better questions, and people would try to help if you put more effort. As per your question, I urge you to read the docs at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html and investigate this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void takePictureNoPreview(Context context){
    // open back facing camera by default
    Camera myCamera=Camera.open();

    if(myCamera!=null){
        try{
            //set camera parameters if you want to
            //...

            // here, the unused surface view and holder
            SurfaceView dummy=new SurfaceView(context)
            myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(dummy.getHolder());    
            myCamera.startPreview(); 

            myCamera.takePicture(null, null, getJpegCallback()):

        } finally {
            myCamera.close();
        }      

    } else {
        //booo, failed!
    }


  private PictureCallback getJpegCallback(){
      PictureCallback jpeg=new PictureCallback() {   
          @Override
          public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
              FileOutputStream fos;
              try {
                  fos = new FileOutputStream("test.jpeg");
                  fos.write(data);
                  fos.close();
              }  catch (IOException e) {
                 //do something about it
              }
          }
      };
   }
}
```

Or try some solutions from this post: [Taking pictures with camera on Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421694/taking-pictures-with-camera-android-programmatically)