# android programming using existing camera application

Tags: android, eclipse

i have write coding for get image by camera with existing camera application, I want to exit from existing camera application after get a result.
my code to get image

```
if (v.getId()==R.id.jepret_button) {
    Intent cameraIntent = 
        new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    String nmFile = contentTxt.getText().toString().substring(0, 8);
    String newPicFile = String.valueOf("/ext_card/DATAMA/GBR/"+nmFile+".jpeg");
    File outFile = new File(String.valueOf(newPicFile));
    Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

Can someone guide me here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will automatically exit from camera app. For reference please follow [Taking pictures with camera on Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421694/taking-pictures-with-camera-on-android-programmatically)