# Press Button To Open a Camera That Then Takes A Picture- 2016

Tags: android, button, camera

I want to be able to take a picture when it is pressed and then store the picture as normal on the local drive. I have tried using Intent but I believe you have to have permissions or something now but I dont know how to do it. Could someone please show me how I would do this for a button please :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking pictures with camera on Android programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421694/taking-pictures-with-camera-on-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use camera you have to set permissions in your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Source: [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

To save photos you should have permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To set intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want something more, here you have [How to](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

Comment: I have tried that but it keeps crashing when i press the button?

Comment: I think its something to do with Permissions? How do I set the permissions for this to enable the camera, I believe this is a android 7 update.

Comment: Try it:<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: Still nothing :'(