# Android: Refreshing the Gallery after saving new images

Tags: android, gallery, mediastore

So in my application I at one point save a bunch of images to a temporary folder, and I want them to show up immediately in the Gallery. Off of a reboot, they do, but otherwise they don't.

I've tried using the sendBroadcast method:

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
     Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But I get a permission error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2628): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=2628, uid=10068
```

Could I be missing a permission in my AndroidManifest, or is this just no longer supported? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Code provided by Petrus in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814533) works for me on Kitkat (4.4):

> ```
> MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
> /*
>  *   (non-Javadoc)
>  * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
>  */
> public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
>   {
>       Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
>       Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
>   }
>     });
> ```

Comment: So when was this no longer supported?

Comment: Which device you are using ? It's not working in nexus 5 nor in nexus 4. Can you help ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either on the Nexus 7 running 4.4.2

Comment: Ah, it works fine .. you just need to pass in the path to the actual file you want to scan

Comment: doesn't doing anything in 4.4.2

Comment: Works like a charm on 4.4.2, for multiple files manually add file paths to the string array. You can't add path of the directory.

Comment: Hi all, i have used above code and am using Moto G5 for testing. Image downloading process was success. but once image downloaded am immediately launching device's default gallery/photo app from my device. but i am unable to find recently downloaded image.. how to fix it.. am trying to refresh gallery/photos app via sendBroadcast too but helpless

Answer (score 9):

I tried `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()`, but it didn't find my custom folder.

I just wanted to share my experience to solving this issue.

At the end, I had `MediaScannerConnection` configured to scan one file at a time and now missing folder that was holding those images showed up.  Every time I download each image, I called `MediaScannerConnection` and file path as Uri instead of folder itself.

Also, many people asked why `sendBroadcast` stop working on kitkat and the answer is that `sendBroadcast` was abused and called too many times and causing system to drain battery or slowdown, so they removed the direct call to prevent abuse which makes sense.  I was hoping to use above solution to the folder that hold all images, but it didn't work on the folder.  I was hoping that finding folder would expose rest of the files within the custom folder, but it didn't in my case.  I am hoping to find better answer in the future...

Here's snippet of my code.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ApplicationContext.context, new String[] { imageFile.getPath() }, null,
              new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                  Log.i(TAG, "Scanned " + path);
                }
              });
```

Comment: Its works from Android 2.2 to Android 4.4.2 and above

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:
after saving your file to folder,write below code

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File("your image path"))));
```

Answer (score 5):

Below code work all device for refreshing the gallery after saving image.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
       Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
       File f1 = new File("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
       Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f1);
       mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
       sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
   } else {
       sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
   }
   sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File("your image path"))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement [MediaScannerConnectionClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient.html) and add the below code.Works perfectly in 4.4 :)

```
MediaScannerConnection conn;

public void startScan(String url) {
    imagepath = url;
    if (conn != null)
        conn.disconnect();
    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(activity.this, activity.this);
    conn.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    try {
        conn.scanFile(imagepath, getMimeType(imagepath));
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {
        //Do something
    }
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know its late but try this can working in all versions:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(out); //out is your file you saved/deleted/moved/copied
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                } else {
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                            Uri.parse("file://"
                                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaScannerConnection instead of SendBroadcast..

```
MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient(
{
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

        if (path.equals(**your filename**.getAbsolutePath()))
        {
            Log.i("Scan Status", "Completed");
            Log.i("uri: ",uri.toString());

            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        conn.scanFile(**your file name**.getAbsolutePath(),null);
    }
});

conn.connect();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
//Gallery Refresh Code         

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                /*
                 *   (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
                 */
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
                {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
            out.close();
```