# ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE doesn't add file to MediaStorage always

Tags: android, mediastore

I have the following line

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + fileOnDownload)));
```

Where `fileOnDownload` is the path of the file like this one:

`/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/song.mp3`

But sometimes when the broadcast is sent, it doesn't reload the `MediaStore` (on Android O at least)
You can see the full code [here](https://gitlab.com/DT3264/DeezLoader-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dt3264/deezloader/MainActivity.java#L107) 
I'm pretty new to Android `MediaStore` so don't be too rude, please :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Refreshing the Gallery after saving new images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624235/android-refreshing-the-gallery-after-saving-new-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code :

```
Intent intent = 
      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and if above code dose not work you can try using MediaScannerConnection !

here is a good tutorial :

https://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/

Comment: I executed the code before making sure the file existed, that's why it worked sometimes

Comment: MediaScannerConnection should be preferred, according to other answers of similar questions - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814533/997940, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19867466/997940