# SimpleDateFormat gives API Error

Tags: java, android

Whenever I use my `SimpleDateFormat` in android it keep giving me the error call requires API level 24. Which doesn't make sense since I refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-the-users-l) tutorial which was a couple of years old.

This is the code that giving out the error

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM,yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

I even try but it's still not working

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM,yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.US);`

Here is my method where I'm having problem with

```
public static long getDateInMillis(String srcDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    long dateInMillis = 0;
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(srcDate);
        dateInMillis = date.getTime();
        return dateInMillis;
    }

    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to give us the error code it's giving? Cheers and maybe some more relevant code to show how you're using that snippet of code. :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's because you imported [android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Check on the top of your Java file

Comment: Where do people like you come from :) Thank you

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Still an `EPIC` solution in 2019

Answer (score 4):

Change your import

```
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

to

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```