# How to format Joda Time to dd-mm-yyyy in android?

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

```
 String DOB = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(dob) * 1000, DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
 // Current
 // YYYY-MM-DD
 // DOB = "1994-05-10T00:00.000Z"

 // Required 
 // DD-MM-YYYY
 // DOB = "10-05-1994"
```

I want to remove the hh:mm:ss and format the date using Joda-Time DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Why do you need Joda to parse a Date?

Comment: basically the dob is in epoch format and i am trying to convert it into required format.

Comment: Right... And Java built in Calendar, Date, and SimpleDateFormat can all help. So again, why Joda?

Comment: then show me how to convert date to epoch and epoch to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

Comment: why joda because SimpleDateFormat call requires API 24.

Comment: No it doesn't? I've used it fine since I started learning Android at API 14

Comment: Import the correct class... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055963/simpledateformat-gives-api-error

Comment: @cricket_007 Why Joda-Time? In general, because `java.util.Date` & `java.util.Calendar` are abysmally troublesome classes, confusing, flawed, and poorly designed. Specifically, because `Date` is in UTC, so parsing a year-month-date string will give incorrect results (unless your intended time zone is always UTC).

Comment: Alright I get it now. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
String textDate ="1994-05-10T00:00.000Z"; //Date to convert

DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); //Default format

SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()); //Needed format

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DATE_FORMAT.parseDateTime(textDate),        DateTimeZone.forID(current.getID()));

Calendar cal=dateTime.toCalendar(Locale.getDefault());

String formatted = SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(cal.getTime()); //Final Required date
```

Comment: gives an error that SimpleDateFormat call requires API 24 current is API 16.

Comment: It's because you imported android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat instead of java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
// pass your DOB String
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(DOB);
// Format for output
DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
// Print the date
System.out.println(dtfOut.print(jodatime));
```

Comment: You don't need to parse the DOB string. You can  convert the long value directly to the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use java.time classes.

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_485_748_890L )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
       .toLocalDate()
       .format(    
           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MM-uuuu" )
                            .withLocale ( Locale.UK )
       )
```

> 29-01-2017

## Joda-Time

If you want a date-only value without a time-of-day, you should be using the [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of java.time is back-ported to Java 6, Java 7, and Android (see below).

## java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of( 1994 , 5 , 10 );
```

If your input is a count of whole seconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), convert to an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_485_748_890L );
```

To view this moment through the lens of a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), assign a time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

To generate a String representing the value of your object, call `toString` for a string in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD.

> ld.toString(): 2017-01-29

For other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. You can specify a formatting pattern, or let the class automatically localize.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MM-uuuu" ).withLocale ( Locale.UK );
String output = ld.format ( f );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-30T04:01:30Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-29T23:01:30-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> ld.toString(): 2017-01-29
>
> output: 29-01-2017

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Now that is very detailed, thanks sir for your kindness