# SimpleDateFormat is not working in Android Kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-version

This method is not working for Android Kitkat, but works in Android Oreo very well.

```
   public String parseDateToTime(String time) {

    String inputPattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa";
    String outputPattern = "hh:mm aa";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    }
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
    }

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            str = outputFormat.format(date);
        }


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("timecon",str);
```

Comment: Make sure you have imported this **`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`** instead of this **`import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;`**

Comment: import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat  I have use this one

Comment: You need to use this **`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`** check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055963/simpledateformat-gives-api-error

Comment: You are always excluding KitKat. `inputFormat` and `outputFormat` are always null due to this condition `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` so the code will skip the try-except block

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The peace of code does not execute as your version check. Because Android **Kitkat** is older than **android N (Nougat).**

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N.
```

It will be executed only N and above OS devices.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you used `Build.VERSION_CODES.N` that means Android **Nougat**, so when Android **Kitkat** is older than android **N** then `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N` will not be true but because android **Oreo** is newer than android Nougat `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N` will be true and your code in if block will work.

you can check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES) to see android VERSION_CODES constants.