# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage deprecated

Tags: android, mediastore

I used to save images using `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` but `insertImage` method is now deprecated. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) say:

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. inserting of images should
>   be performed using [MediaColumns#IS_PENDING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#IS_PENDING), which offers richer
>   control over lifecycle.

I don't really get it, since `MediaColumns.IS_PENDING` is just a flag, how am I supposed to use it?

Should I use `ContentValues` ?

Comment: Call `insert()` with a `ContentValues` to get a `Uri` that you can use for writing out your content. For the `IS_PENDING` stuff, your `insert()` call would have `IS_PENDING` set to `1`. Then, after you write out the content, you would `update()` the item with `IS_PENDING` set to `0`. See [this code snippet](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/blob/v0.5/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt#L69-102) for an example, though in my case I am saving a video, not an image.

Comment: Question: What is happening in this piece of code: 

 `uri?.let {
          resolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
            val sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(outputStream))

            response.body()?.source()?.let { sink.writeAll(it) }
            sink.close()
          }`

Comment: In my case, I am downloading a video from a URL to the device. `response.body().source()` gives me an Okio `Source` representing the bytes of the video that I am downloading. `Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(outputStream))` gives me an Okio `Sink` representing where I am writing the bytes to, and `writeAll()` writes all the bytes from the `Source` to the `Sink`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145) for the Square-approved approach.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110559/6039240

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> SOLVED

The code suggested from @CommonsWare has no problem, except the fact that if you are programming with `targetSdkVersion 29`, you must add the condition:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { //this one
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you use those content values after that?

Comment: check out this clas I used the exact same code cuz it's this use case:
https://github.com/coroutineDispatcher/pocket_treasure/blob/master/gallery_module/src/main/java/com/sxhardha/gallery_module/image/FullImageFragment.kt

Comment: What happen if I didn't set `MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING` to 1?

Comment: The file you wrote won't be accessible to other apps.

Answer (score 19):

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. inserting of images should
> be performed using MediaColumns#IS_PENDING, which offers richer
> control over the lifecycle.

Either I'm too stupid to understand the docs or the Google team really needs to refactor the documentation.

Anyways, posting the complete answer from the [links](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/blob/v0.5/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt#L69-102) provided by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) and [coroutineDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8914336/coroutinedispatcher)

**Step 1:** ***Decide on which API level you are***

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) saveImageInQ(imageBitMap)
    else saveImageInLegacy(imageBitMap)
```

**Step 2:** ***Save the image in **Q** style***

```
//Make sure to call this function on a worker thread, else it will block main thread
fun saveImageInQ(bitmap: Bitmap):Uri {   
    val filename = "IMG_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
    var fos: OutputStream? = null
    val imageUri: Uri? = null
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    }

    //use application context to get contentResolver
    val contentResolver = application.contentResolver

    contentResolver.also { resolver ->               
        imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
        fos = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
    }

    fos?.use { bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, it) }

    contentValues.clear()
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    resolver.update(imageUri, contentValues, null, null)
          
    return imageUri
}
```

**Step 3:** ***If not on **Q** save the image in legacy style***

```
//Make sure to call this function on a worker thread, else it will block main thread
fun saveTheImageLegacyStyle(bitmap:Bitmap){
    val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val image = File(imagesDir, filename)
    fos = FileOutputStream(image)
    fos?.use {bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)}
}
```

This should get you rolling!

Comment: in the Step 2, `resolver` variable is missing.. would you update the code please?

Comment: `resolver` is the `contentResolver` object you get from your `applicationContext`

Comment: thanks for the completed code....i use your function saveImageInQ and its working like charm

Answer (score 6):

#### Sum up of all the answers, but also refactored versions of each one.

You can skip the additions to `AndroidManifest.xml` and `filepaths.xml` if your app already uses a file provider.

###### Update (12/2022)

I had to replace `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` with `applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` as it seems to be crashing in earlier versions of Android. Please be sure you provide the root directory in `filepaths.xml`.

###### Save as PNG

```
/**
 * Saves a bitmap as a PNG file.
 *
 * Note that `.png` extension is added to the filename.
 */
fun Bitmap.saveAsPNG(filename: String) = "$filename.png".let { name ->
    if (SDK_INT < Q) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        val file = File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES), name)
        FileOutputStream(file).use { compress(PNG, 100, it) }
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(applicationContext,
            arrayOf(file.absolutePath), null, null)
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext,
            "${ applicationContext.packageName }.provider", file)
    } else {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            put(RELATIVE_PATH, DIRECTORY_DCIM)
            put(IS_PENDING, 1)
        }

        val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val uri = resolver.insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
        uri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
            ?.use { compress(PNG, 100, it) }

        values.clear()
        values.put(IS_PENDING, 0)
        uri?.also {
            resolver.update(it, values, null, null) }
    }
}
```

###### Save as JPG

```
/**
 * Saves a bitmap as a Jpeg file.
 *
 * Note that `.jpg` extension is added to the filename.
 */
fun Bitmap.saveAsJPG(filename: String) = "$filename.jpg".let { name ->
    if (SDK_INT < Q)
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        FileOutputStream(File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES), name))
            .use { compress(JPEG, 100, it) }
    else {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
            put(RELATIVE_PATH, DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            put(IS_PENDING, 1)
        }

        val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val uri = resolver.insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
        uri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
            ?.use { compress(JPEG, 70, it) }

        values.clear()
        values.put(IS_PENDING, 0)
        uri?.also {
            resolver.update(it, values, null, null) }
    }
}
```

###### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

###### res/xml/filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="whatever"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

###### Imports (in case you are missing something)

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q
import android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
import android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
import android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
```

Comment: is there java version?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for contributing [iCantC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9987309/icantc) on
**Step 2: Save the image in Q style**.

I ran into some issues with memory usage in Android Studio, which I had to open Sublime to fix. To fix this error:

```kotlin
e: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This is the code I used as my use case is for PNG images, any value of `bitmap.compress` less than 100 is likely not useful.
Previous version would not work on API 30 so I updated contentValues `RELATIVE_PATH` to `DIRECTORY_DCIM` also `contentResolver.insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ...`

```kotlin
   
    private val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH:mm:ss z", Locale.getDefault()
    )
    private val legacyOrQ: (Bitmap) -> Uri = { if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        saveImageInQ(it) else legacySave(it) }
    
    private fun saveImageInQ(bitmap: Bitmap): Uri {
        val filename = "${title}_of_${dateFormatter.format(Date())}.png"
        val fos: OutputStream?
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
            put(MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            put(RELATIVE_PATH, DIRECTORY_DCIM)
            put(IS_PENDING, 1)
        }

        //use application context to get contentResolver
        val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val uri = contentResolver.insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
        uri?.let { contentResolver.openOutputStream(it) }.also { fos = it }
        fos?.use { bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, it) }
        fos?.flush()
        fos?.close()

        contentValues.clear()
        contentValues.put(IS_PENDING, 0)
        uri?.let {
            contentResolver.update(it, contentValues, null, null)
        }
        return uri!!
    }
```

**Step 3: If not on Q save the image in legacy style**

```kotlin
private fun legacySave(bitmap: Bitmap): Uri {
        val appContext = applicationContext
        val filename = "${title}_of_${dateFormatter.format(Date())}.png"
        val directory = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(directory, filename)
        val outStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream)
        outStream.flush()
        outStream.close()
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(appContext, arrayOf(file.absolutePath),
            null, null)
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(appContext, "${appContext.packageName}.provider",
            file)
    }
```

**Step 4: Create a custom FileProvider**

```kotlin
package com.example.background.workers.provider

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider

class WorkerFileProvider : FileProvider() {

}
```

**step 5: update your AndroidManifest.xml**

changes from

```xml
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

to

```xml
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/png"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name=".workers.provider.WorkerFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**step 6: add a resource under xml for FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS**
in my case I needed the pictures folder

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="pictures" path="Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding a second answer as I am not sure if anyone cares about version checks but if you do their are more steps, hmm...
Starting from

**step 5: update your AndroidManifest.xml**

changes from

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

to

```
        <activity android:name=".legacy.LegacyMyActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
        <provider
            android:name=".workers.provider.WorkerFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:enabled="@bool/atMostKitkat"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <activity-alias android:name=".legacy.LegacyMyActivity"
            android:targetActivity=".MyActivity"
            android:enabled="@bool/atMostJellyBeanMR2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

**step 6: add a resource under xml for FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS** is same as my previous answer

**step 7: add a resource under res/values for bool.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="atMostJellyBeanMR2">true</bool>
    <bool name="atMostKitkat">false</bool>
</resources>
```

**step 8: and another under res/values-v19**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="atMostJellyBeanMR2">false</bool>
    <bool name="atMostKitkat">true</bool>
</resources>
```

**step 9: finally if you need to view the saved file**
so the important change is `actionView.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`

```kotlin
   binding.seeFileButton.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.outputUri?.let { currentUri ->
                 val actionView = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, currentUri)
                 actionView.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                 actionView.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.run {
                    startActivity(actionView)
             }
        }
   }
```

Comment: some would argue that version check is an important consideration, which I agree but just don't know by how much. Also I wanted to keep my original answer a little short

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun saveImage29(bitmap: Bitmap){
        val insertUri =
            contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ContentValues())
        try {
            val outputStream = insertUri?.let { contentResolver.openOutputStream(it, "rw") }
            if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,outputStream)){
                toast("保存成功")
            }else{
                toast("保存失败")
            }
        }catch (e:FileNotFoundException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).