# How to download image/video file in Android R with help of MediaStore?

Tags: android, mediastore

As getExternalStoragePublicDirectory has been deprecated in Android Q and recommendation is to use `MediaStore` API

Here is my Image URL `https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/21/06/41/bulldog-5071407_1280.jpg`

I want to download this image file and want to save the shared folder i.e. Downloads or Pictures Folder as per `MediaStore` API

Below is the sample code

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

Note: **compileSdkVersion 30**

I want an example of How to download an Image/Video file in Android R and save it into the download folder location with MediaStore.

Comment: `Now question is How to download Image/Video file and save into uri location.` The media store can not help you with downloading so i do not understand the subject of your post.

Comment: An uri from the media store or from a file provider. It's all the same. Apparently you wanna download to an uri. Well you can do that exactly the same as before Android R.

Comment: @blackapps how to download file? and save into Downloads folder with help of MediaStore

Comment: As said before: The media store cannot help you with downloading.

Comment: @blackapps can you give me one sample for doenload file which support in android R

Comment: https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos demonstrates downloading videos using OkHttp and storing them to locations provided by `MediaStore` on Android 10+.

Comment: "Please share working sample for Android R" -- I did, in my preceding comment. That is described in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html) and [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q). [Here is another sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/VideoTagger), from [this book](https://commonsware.com/R).

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Kanaiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143026/kanaiya-katarmal) I answered an improvement on MediaStore answer [MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726896/mediastore-images-media-insertimage-deprecated/67508416#67508416)

I did use workManager and viewModel not sure if that would apply to your use-case, I did test my answer on API 26 and on API 30.

My working [sample](https://github.com/braghome/BlurActivity/tree/start_kotlin) is just a 2018 workmanager codelab for which I made minor changes to remove a depreciated api call, thanks for the original idea [commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)

Comment: In your case as you are saving a JPG so on the compress you could/should use a value less than 100

Answer (score 0):

In order to save it on android 10. Then after calling the insert method you will get the URI then call

```html
os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
os.close();
```

In Android 10 calling insert method is not enough

Your code will look like this

```html
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues); 

OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
os.close();
```

Comment: what to do if it is a video file?